# How can I use Min in a case statement

Tags: mysql, case, min

I'm getting the error:
 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

How can I fix this?

here is the sql.

```
Select 
 HEADER_ID, 
 CASE 
  WHEN MIN(OPPTY_HEADER_ID) THEN STATCD='SP66'ELSE STATCD AS STACD,
 TYPE, NL_IND
FROM nl_dups_load
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? And is this some kind of RDBMS problem?

Comment: I should have included more info. This table is a table of duplicate header_ids. Each header_id has and oppty_header_id. so there are 2 oppty_header_id to each header_id.  so I wan to take the min oppty_header_id per header id and change its statcd.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need a true/false result in the first clause of your `CASE WHEN` statement for it to function.

Changing it to something like:

```
Select HEADER_ID 
  , CASE WHEN MIN(OPPTY_HEADER_ID) > 0 THEN STATCD = 'SP66' ELSE STATCD END AS STACD
  , TYPE
  , NL_IND
FROM nl_dups_load
```

Will 'fix' that particular error, but its result may not be what you're looking for.  Also, I do not believe that you can use an aggregate function (i.e., 'MIN') in a CASE statement in that format, so you may come across another error if you fix the original one.

You will have to better explain your question and desired SQL result.

EDIT:

> I should have included more info. This table is a table of duplicate
>   header_ids. Each header_id has and oppty_header_id. so there are 2
>   oppty_header_id to each header_id. so I wan to take the min
>   oppty_header_id per header id and change its statcd.

Sounds like you want something like the following (with loads of assumptions being made).   **Test this before using it, as UPDATE queries are not easily reversed.**

```
UPDATE A
SET A.STATCD = 'SP66'
FROM nl_dups_load AS A
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT B.HEADER_ID, MIN(OPPTY_HEADER_ID) AS MinOppty 
   FROM nl_dups_load AS B GROUP BY B.HEADER_ID
) AS C ON A.HEADER_ID = C.HEADER_ID AND A.OPPTY_HEADER_ID = C.MinOppty
```

Though, I'd really need to see some example rows of your source table and an example of those same rows with the changes made in a resulting table to know for sure that this is what you're looking to do.